# Country dimension in Analytics Reporting API v4

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-filters

I want to get a report from Google Analytics v4 for pageviews by country. Since my website is targeting a specific region, I'm filtering by countries I'm most interested in using ga:countryIsoCode dimension so I don't have to type complete country name in the filter.
Now I'd be also interested in getting pageviews for all other countries combined into 'other' entry. What would be the easiest way to achieve that?
I've tried dynamic segments so far adding ga:segment to dimensions and a NOT filter in the segment with the same rule I used for filtering counties (except ga:countryIsoCode isn't allowed in segments, so I used ga:country). This produced 3 rows of data with each of three countries appearing along with 'other' every time.
I'd appreciate an advice on this as it seems like a common use case to me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve that by using segments. This approach doesn't allow to batch requests though unless all of them have the same segment definition. Also, there're limitations on the number of segments to include in the report request. Very surprised this functionality is so hard to achieve. For interested, there's an example request:

```
{
    "reportRequests": [{
        "viewId": "ga:XXXXXXXXX",
        "dateRanges": [{
            "startDate": "YYYY-MM-DD",
            "endDate": "YYYY-MM-DD"
        }],
        "metrics": [{
            "expression": "ga:pageviews"
        }, {
            "expression": "ga:sessions"
        }],
        "dimensions": [{
            "name": "ga:segment"
        }],
        "segments": [{
            "dynamicSegment": {
        "name": "Other",
                "sessionSegment": {
                    "segmentFilters": [{
            "not": "True",
                        "simpleSegment": {
                            "orFiltersForSegment": [{
                                "segmentFilterClauses": [{
                                    "dimensionFilter": {
                                        "dimensionName": "ga:country",
                                        "operator": "IN_LIST",
                                        "expressions": ["United States", "United Kingdom"]
                                    }
                                }]
                            }]
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        },
    {
            "dynamicSegment": {
        "name": "United States",
                "sessionSegment": {
                    "segmentFilters": [{
                        "simpleSegment": {
                            "orFiltersForSegment": [{
                                "segmentFilterClauses": [{
                                    "dimensionFilter": {
                                        "dimensionName": "ga:country",
                                        "operator": "EXACT",
                                        "expressions": "United States"
                                    }
                                }]
                            }]
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        },
    {
      "dynamicSegment": {
        "name": "United Kingdom",
        "sessionSegment": {
          "segmentFilters": [{
            "simpleSegment": {
              "orFiltersForSegment": [{
                "segmentFilterClauses": [{
                  "dimensionFilter": {
                    "dimensionName": "ga:country",
                    "operator": "EXACT",
                    "expressions": "United Kingdom"
                  }
                }]
              }]
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    }],
        'hideTotals': 'true',
        'hideValueRanges': 'true'
    }]
}
```